# Pandas: get value from specific row and column by name and year

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

there is a DataFrame of cast which contains title, year, name, character, n.. etc.

[image]

1. How many leading (n=1) roles were available to actors, and how many to
   actresses, in each year of the 1950s?
2. List the 10 actors/actresses that have the most leading roles (n=1) since the 1990's.
3. List, in order by year, each of the films in which Frank Oz has played more than
   1 role.

The questions above this line unfortunately I did not succeed.

I tried some functions in pandas but, no one fit to these questions

I would be delighted if someone could help

Comment: What is your code? It looks like homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `loc()` method. Below link gives the complete discription
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-extracting-rows-using-loc/